# Build Sundials with MKL

Tags: cmake, lapack, blas, intel-mkl, sundials

I need to build Sundials (as a dependency for another C/C++ library) on a Linux cluster which provides only MKL as BLAS and LAPACK support.

As far as I know, unlike other versions, the MKL BLAS and LAPACK wrappers are not self-contained at link time but require linking against MKL core and/or other libraries as well.

So how (if at all) can I tell CMake what to include in order to successfully build Sundials? Is it possible and safe to use flags like

```
$ cmake (...) -DBLAS_LIBRARIES=/path/to/mkl/<several files grouped together>
```

and what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Have you tried to build Sundials as is, without additional options? It seems that CMake should correctly work with MKL as BLAS.

Comment: You mean without specifying any paths or library files at all? No, I didn't. To be honest it didn't cross my mind, so thanks for suggesting it, I will give it a go and let you know what happens.

Comment: Ok now I did it and it worked! Thanks a lot, sometimes the solution is staring you right in the face!